# How to send email to anyone as a Google Groups account?

Tags: gmail, google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

We have a group created in GSuite and is configured to receive incoming mail from external domain, i.e. `posting permission` is being set as `"Public"`.

But what if a member of the group wants to send or reply to email as the group account (for e.g. `social@example.com` instead of `person@example.com`), then how do you do that?